# What's the difference between "I..." and "I have..."?

Tags: grammar, differences, tenses, syntactic-analysis, past-tense

What's the difference between "I..." and "I have..."? For example, what would be the difference between saying "I recently moved back to Portland" and "I've recently moved back to Portland"?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "I moved to..." You should specify a date like:

I moved to NY two years ago.

And when you use the "I have moved..." Form it sounds like you just did it a few time ago.